Install python turtle on ubuntu 24.04
I need some help with installing the 'turtle' python module on Ubuntu 24.04 (noble numbat).
First I tried installing via pip:
$ pip install turtle
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.



In Python 3, the turtle module is included as part of the standard library. To verify that the turtle module is installed, open the terminal and type:
python3 -c "import turtle; print(turtle.__doc__)"

The first line of the results of python3 -c "import turtle; print(turtle.__doc__)" is:
Turtle graphics is a popular way for introducing programming to
kids. ...


Is that the same on venv?

Yes, it will work on venv too assuming that the venv has Python 3 installed in it. In Python 3, the turtle module is included as part of the standard library.
